# Need Help parsing ProjectInfo.CS file with NANT Regex task

Tags: c#, regex, nant

I'm trying to read the version information in ProjectInfo.CS and ProjectInfo.VB in my buildscript so that I can later update it but I'm getting the following errors.

1. Missing Required WhiteSpace
2. Missing attribute value on attribute 'AssemblyInformationalVersion'

EDIT: In my regex pattern, I'm trying to use named group matching.

Here is the code I'm using:

```
  <loadfile file="${ProjectInfoCS}" property="ProjectInfoCSData"/>

  <regex pattern='AssemblyInformationalVersion\(\"(?'AssemblyInformationalVersion'\d{1,}\.\d{1,}\.\d{1,}\.\d{1,})\"\)'
         input="${ProjectInfoCSData}"
         options="Multiline,IgnoreCase"
         failonerror="false"/>

  <echo message="AssemblyInformationVersion=${AssemblyInformationalVersion}" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this pattern

```
 <regex pattern="(?'AssemblyInformationVersion'\d{1,}\.\d{1,}\.\d{1,}\.\d{1,})"
         input="${ProjectInfoCSData}"
         options="Multiline,IgnoreCase"
         failonerror="false"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
    <loadfile file="versioninfo.cs" property="versioninfo" />

    <regex pattern="assembly: AssemblyVersionAttribute\(&quot;(?'version'.*)&quot;\)"
         input="${versioninfo}"
         options="Multiline,IgnoreCase"
         failonerror="false" />

    <echo message="Version is ${version}" />
```